# How does paypal store credit card numbers?

Tags: encryption, credit-card, hsm

How does Paypal store credit card numbers?

Have they published any information this?

As for now I would say that they encrypt the card numbers and store the key in an HSM, but this is just a personal guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely confidential, so I bet you won't get a 100% answer to this one.
However, we [know](http://www.visa.com/splisting/searchGrsp.do) PayPal are PCI-DSS compliant.

This means they are compliant with 3.4 in the standard, which states: "Render PAN unreadable anywhere it is stored". That means with a probability of at least 99% that they store the credit card numbers encrypted. It is possible with compensating controls to store them unencrypted, but it's very difficult to get a compensation control to 3.4 approved by a QSA.

Regarding HSM, we must guess again. It is definitely possible to comply with PCI-DSS without using a HSM, it's just way harder. For a company with a small budget, they might want to avoid the cost purchasing a HSM. For a company like PayPal, it's a no-brainer, so I'm 99% sure they're using a HSM to manage their crypto keys.